# MUI Textfield not accepting decimal input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a textfield to enter unitPrice

```
   const [unitPrice, setUnitPrice] = useState(0);
   <TextField
      label="Unit Price"
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
      value={unitPrice.toString()}
      type="number"
      fullWidth
      inputProps={{
        min: "0",
        step: "1.0",
      }}
      onChange={handleUnitPriceChange}
      onBlur={handleLineBlur}
    />
```

And an onchange function that uses a custom function that handles number input. The purpose of the function is to prevent the user from entering more than two decimal digits.

```
const handleUnitPriceChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    handleNumberInput(event.target.value, setUnitPrice);
  };
```

```
export const handleNumberInput = (
  number: string,
  setValue: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
) => {
  const parsedValue = parseFloat(number);

  if (!isNaN(parsedValue)) {
    const roundedValue = parseFloat(parsedValue.toFixed(2));
    setValue(roundedValue);
  } else {
    setValue(0);
  }
};
```

When I input a decimal digit in the textfield(2.22 for example) and try to submit my form, I get

> "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are "2 and 3"

I already tried using inputProps step but it didn't work.
How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 2):

The step attribute in the inputProps should be set to "0.01" instead of "1.0" to allow decimal values with two decimal places.

```
<TextField
  label="Unit Price"
  variant="outlined"
  margin="normal"
  value={unitPrice}
  type="number"
  fullWidth
  inputProps={{
    min: "0",
    step: "0.01",
  }}
  onChange={handleUnitPriceChange}
  onBlur={handleLineBlur}
/>
```